# Vue.js quasar-framework - "vue-excel-editor" integration

Tags: excel, vue.js, quasar-framework

Need to use excel as a part of an input form in my quasar app. The goal is to resolve this problem, or propose a alternative integration that has proven to work.

What have I done:

1. Instal "vue-excel-editor" package, by running:

```
npm install vue-excel-editor
```

2. Add below code to quasar.conf.js:

```
boot: [
  '...',
  '...',
  'vue-excel-editor'
],
```

3. Add below code to created /boot/vue-excel-editor.js

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import VueExcelEditor from 'vue-excel-editor'

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  // Set VueExcelEditor instance on app
  app.use(VueExcelEditor)
})

export { VueExcelEditor }
```

acc to info from vue-excel-editor ducumentation please see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-excel-editor

4. Created a basic component just for checking:

```
<template>
  <vue-excel-editor v-model="jsondata" filter-row>
    <vue-excel-column field="user" label="User ID" type="string" width="80px" />
    <vue-excel-column field="name" label="Name" type="string" width="150px" />
    <vue-excel-column
      field="phone"
      label="Contact"
      type="string"
      width="130px"
    />
    <vue-excel-column
      field="gender"
      label="Gender"
      type="select"
      width="50px"
      :options="['F', 'M', 'U']"
    />
    <vue-excel-column field="age" label="Age" type="number" width="70px" />
    <vue-excel-column
      field="birth"
      label="Date Of Birth"
      type="date"
      width="80px"
    />
  </vue-excel-editor>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: "Spreadsheet",
};
</script>
```

And after adding this component to previously working page I'm getting this console:

```
 App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/vue-excel-editor/src/VueExcelEditor.vue?vue&type=template&id=cf2e49d2&scoped=true

Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js):

VueCompilerError: <template v-for> key should be placed on the <template> tag.
at C:\Users\..\..\..\Code\..\frontend\node_modules\vue-excel-editor\src\VueExcelEditor.vue:124:21
122|                      }"
123|                      :style="Object.assign(cellStyle(record, item), renderColumnCellStyle(item))"
124|                      :key="p"
   |                      ^^^^^^^^
125|                      @mouseover="cellMouseOver"
126|                      @mousemove="cellMouseMove">{{ item.toText(record[item.name]) }}</td>

 App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/vue-excel-editor/src/VueExcelEditor.vue?vue&type=template&id=cf2e49d2&scoped=true

Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js):

VueCompilerError: <template v-for> key should be placed on the <template> tag.
at C:\..\..\..\..\Code\..\frontend\node_modules\vue-excel-editor\src\VueExcelEditor.vue:144:21
142|                      }"
143|                      :style="renderColumnCellStyle(field)"
144|                      :key="`f${p}`">{{ summary[field.name] }}</td>
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
145|                </template>
146|              </tr>

 App •  COMPILATION FAILED  • Please check the log above for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Vue 3.0? Now vue-excel-editor component is only for Vue 2.0.

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html#with-template-v-for

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I'm using "quasar": "^2.1.1" so it should be based on vue 3.0. Any plans for making it compatible with 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of Vue Excel Editor for Vue 3 available on https://github.com/cscan/vue3-excel-editor.
This should resolve your problem above.